# Mock HTTP server for Mule FunctionalTest

Tags: testing, mocking, mule

I have built a module In Mule to process HTTP responses for a specific use case. For my unit tests I need to mock a http server. Whats the recommended approach to do this with Mule Functional tests? Does Mule provide any testing utilities for this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create mock servers that stubs out remote servers with the `HTTP` transport and the `test:component` (from the test module), like for example:

```
<flow name="acmeApiStub">
    <http:inbound-endpoint ref="acmeApiEndpoint" />
    <test:component />
</flow>
```

The `<test:component />` allows you to set fake responses, throw exceptions, etc... to simulate different cases.

As a side note, for cases when I want to use a web server that has nothing to do with Mule (like to guarantee things are not working just because I have Mule on both sides during test), I usually turn to [Simple](http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/), a nice embeddable Java HTTP server perfectly fitted for tests.

Also I advise you to use dynamically assigned ports for your tests so that way you won't risk conflicts when building on a CI server. For this, in your configuration, use property placeholders for ports, like `http.port` and have the functional test assign them for you with:

```
@Rule
public DynamicPort httpPort = new DynamicPort("http.port");
```

Comment: Thanks David, I originally looked at the ftc, but what I need to do is check that the http server recieves the correct http headers from my outbound endpoint. Something I couldn't figure out how to do with the ftc. Do you think this more suited to useing an embedded server like Simple? So I can check Mule sent it the correct http headers etc?

Comment: The FTC is super dumb with its default message accumulation mechanism: for any reason, it stores only the payload and not the headers :( You can go around this limitation by using `getFunctionalTestComponent` in your test case to retrieve an instance of the component, then `setEventCallback` to register a custom callback where you will perform the headers tests (using `eventContext.getMessage()` to get them).